# Icon in python.exe program (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

In my program, I use the tkinter library to create a window program, but I have a problem with the icon.
I have error (when start program without icon.ico in the folder):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 169, in <module>
    main_app()
  File "program.py", line 133, in main_app
    root.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 2136, in wm_iconbitmap
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "icon.ico" not defined
```

In the code I have:

```
def main_app():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('program')
    root.geometry('300x200')
    root.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
    -rest of program (buttons, etc.)
    root.mainloop()
```

When I build to EXE (I try with console and gui pyinstaller) with commands:

```
Pyinstaller GUI (pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --icon
"C:/Users/Karol/Desktop/python/icon.ico"
"C:/Users/Karol/Desktop/python/python.py"
In console (pyinstaller -F -w -i icon.ico program.py)
```

Is there any solution to make the program work without the icon in the folder? Only it was already in the program.

I describe in my question, I have a problem with tkinter libraby and try to solve it.

Comment: Put the full path into the function call, e.g.`root.iconbitmap(r'c:\Python32\DLLs\py.ico')`

Comment: You need to add the .ICO file into the executable explicitly using `--add-data` of `PyInstaller`.  The `-i icon.ico` just set the icon of the boot-loader of the executable, but not included in the payload of the python application.

Comment: Also take a look on [PyInstaller Run-time Information](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html).